# Auto Layout Scale Constraint Prop

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, constraints, scaling

I am new to swift and trying to make a resizable view based on the device type. I am using constraints and I was wondering if it was possible to have a Horizontal Space Constraint that instead of having a constant value, scaled proportionally based on the size of the device.

Right now I have a Horizontal Space Constraint with a constant value of 56.

I want it so that when the device becomes smaller the constant value of 56 also becomes smaller.

Cheers

Comment: NSLayoutConstraint has a property called "constant" which is what you are describing. There is also a property called "multiplier" which will do exactly what you are asking. Play with the constraints "multiplier" and it will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the leading and trailing constraints of view to scale it horizontally.

`Select the view --> editor --> pin --> Leading space to superview`

and do the same to add trailing space.

you can set it other way by selecting pin button in right bottom corner:
[image]